# JQGrid How to bind data when the colModel name is different from the column name in Database

Tags: jqgrid

My Server is returning data with column Names which I am not comfortable with. I want the JQgrid to have colNames differently i.e. I give my own names. How do I map tat with the data.

Comment: It's possible and can be done while assigning your objects (*server columns*) to the json Object inside the method or controller, then you can pass that json object to the grid. It will be very useful for others to help you, when you put the codes which you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. In colModel there is a prop XMLMap where we define a function. I assigned XMLMap to each column and inside the function the data was decoded.